# Check if attribute of given node has one of the values from the list

Tags: xslt

I need to take some action (print something to target XML) when a given attribute has one of the values from the list.

Say I have:

```
<xsl:when test="$Path/To/List[1]/ELEMENT@attribute = 'code1'">
    <xsl:element name="SOME_OTHER_ELEMENT">
        <xsl-value-of select="$Path/To/List[1]/OTHER_ELEMENT/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:when>
```

But I need to do the same, when the @attribute has the value code3, code7, code11, code12 and code15.

I could, of course, use `or` clause and duplicate test expression X times, but this would be terribly long, I was looking for something like `in` operator, but I found nothing.

Is it possible to achieve given functionality in less verbose way than using X `or` statements, and how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 and later you can use `<xsl:when test="$Path/To/List[1]/ELEMENT[@attribute = ('code1', 'code3', 'code7', 'code12', 'code15')]">` respectively (not sure about your original code with the syntax error `ELEMENT@attribute`) `<xsl:when test="$Path/To/List[1]/ELEMENT/@attribute = ('code1', 'code3', 'code7', 'code12', 'code15')">`.